# PayPal Donation Button - How can I remove the 'recurring donation (monthly)' option?

Tags: html, button, paypal

I've included a PayPal donate button on my website.

When visitors click through, they are sent to a PayPal page where they can log in and input their donation amount.

However, they are also given the option to make their donation a monthly recurrence. This isn't really suitable for our site and I wondered how I could remove the tick box?

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAHs7.jpg

PayPal suggested that if I wanted to remove an option from the button, I 'would need to edit the html code so that the option is taken out and no longer available' to my visitors.

The unprotected code reads as follows:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"    target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="IDENTIFICATION NUMBER">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="DONATION FUND NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:fund.png:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="BUTTON ARTWORK" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the paypal website I see two options one is for one time donation and another is for recurring donation (subscription). 
You might want to use the one time donation option.

For what Paypal suggested: you will have to either search and remove the HTML tags  that show the recurring option or comment them out by enclosing them within HTML comment

If you can remove any sensitive information from your HTML code and post it here. I (or someone else) can quickly tell you what to remove or comment.

Update after looking at HTML:
Does not look like the HTML code showing the recurring option is on your website. The form that you are submitting triggers that form on paypal's website.

I have seen options for one-time donations on other non-profits.
sample : https://eclipse.org/donate/
I have not done this by myself. I suggest you go to paypal and re-generate the donate button/html and make sure you are using the one time donation option.

Comment: Thanks @Adi Pandit, I've posted the code as a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's definitely the 'Donation' Option I've used, rather than the 'Subscription' one :/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Adi Pandit.

I did use the Donation Option rather than the Subscription, which is why it's confusing.

The unprotected code reads as follows:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"    target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="IDENTIFICATION NUMBER">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="DONATION FUND NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:fund.png:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="BUTTON ARTWORK" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```